# Create numbers from 50-100 only using 1,2,3 and 5

Tags: mathematics

Create numbers from 50-100 only using 1,2,3 and 5. No repeats and you have to use each number. Also, you can use any operation! thanks :)?

Comment: Welcome to PSE. Do take a look at the [tour page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with how this site works. Also, please note that questions of this form often tend to be closed as being too broad ([link](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/handling-underspecified-make-this-number-from-these-digits-questions)). For example, Solutus Immensus's answer shows how such a broad question can result in an equally broad answer.

Comment: Try to avoid these kinds of questions unless you are 100% sure that this is a clever riddle that is not too broad. Almost all kinds of these questions are too broad. Welcome to Puzzling SE by the way! Hope you stay :D

Comment: Also, try to avoid placing your entire riddle/puzzle in the title, because the point of a title is to give other users an idea about what the puzzle is about or to give an interesting hook to draw them in.

Comment: With "any" you mean +,-,*,/,! and taking the square root and one number to the power of the other?

Answer (score 4):

If you can use *any* operation:

> Let $ f_n(a,b,c,d)=n$ be a 4-ary constant operation.
>  Then $ f_n(1,2,3,5) = n $ for $ n = 50, 51, ..., 100 $

Comment: Or even better, let $\boxed{???}$ be the magical mathematical function that maps all integers to all integers and hence it will be trivial to create any integer. @zar do you see why this is too broad?

Comment: What you described is not a function

Comment: that's why it's magical...